# Using Font Awesome and Fort Awesome together

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-awesome

I use both [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) and [Fort Awesome](https://fortawesome.com/) in my Rails app and am having some trouble because both use the `.fa` class to specify the font.  I want to use a CDN for both fonts but I want the font to default to Fort Awesome when an element has the `.fa` class, and then use Font Awesome when both `.fa` and `.fa-standard` are present.

**Example:**

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>               --> use Fort Awesome
<i class="fa fa-standard fa-twitter"></i> --> use Font Awesome
```

Is there a way to achieve this while using CDNs for both fonts?

Comment: Fort or Font overrides icons by fa class? I'd try to use for Font Awesome classes fas/far/fal/fab instead of fa.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mix such things ... better use one icons set

Answer (score -1):

You may achieve this by creating a custom set of CSS rules that uniquely target the **Font** Awesome and **Fort** Awesome icons used in your Rails app.

Here's an example:

```
/* use Fort Awesome by default for .fa elements */
.fa:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "FortAwesomeBrandsRegular";
}

/* use Font Awesome when both .fa and .fa-standard are present */
.fa.fa-standard:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

Now any element with the  `.fa class` will use the Fort Awesome font by default. If an element has both  `.fa`  and `.fa-standard` classes, it will use the Font Awesome font instead.